# Asp.net webform con timer y update panel se queda congelada

Tags: ajax, asp.net, timer, updatepanel

Se trata de una web desarrollada en `Asp.net` que utiliza `Update Panels` y `Timers` para refrescar la información.

En la parte del `aspx` tendría algo así:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="myscriptmanager"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbHora"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbContador"></asp:Label>
            <asp:gridview runat="server" id="grid1" />
            <asp:gridview runat="server" id="grid2"/>                    

            <asp:timer runat="server" id="mytimer" enabled="true" interval="1000"></asp:timer>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Y en el `code behind` algo de este estilo:

```
    Private Sub mytimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mytimer.Tick
    Dim intTimer15 As Integer = ViewState("contadorTimer")

    intTimer15 += 1

    LeerInfoBD(nuevoItem)
    If nuevoItem then
       LbContador.text=0
    else
       LbContador.Text=Cint(lbcontador.text)+1
    end if

    If intTimer15 >= 15 Then
        lbHora.Text = Now
        Cargar_Grid1(grid1)
        Cargar_Grid2(grid2) 

        intTimer15 = 0
    End If


    ViewState("contadorTimer") = intTimer15 

End Sub
```

En la parte del código `aspx` también está este código para controlar errores en el lado cliente:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
                {
                   if (args.get_error() != undefined)
                   {
                       var errorMessage = args.get_error().message;
                       args.set_errorHandled(true);
                       localstorage.set("logerror", errorMessage);
                   }
                 }
```

El problema que me estoy encontrando es que cada X días el contador está detenido. 
Si entro en las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador, veo que la página ha dejado de hacer post. Es decir, que el timer ha dejado de funcionar.

- ¿Es posible que el fallo se deba a estar refrescando la página
  demasiadas veces (un tick del timer cada 1s) y tal vez provoca un
  fallo de memoria en el navegador o en el propio servidor web?
- ¿existe un límite en el número de peticiones que una página puede
  hacer a un servidor en una misma sesión?
- ¿Cual puede ser la causa de este comportamiento?

En los procedimientos que llamo desde el 'timer' uso bloques try-catch para controlar las excepciones, y no veo que cuando se detiene el timer sea por una excepción en el codebehind.

Tampoco se guarda nada en localstorage, por lo que no se ha producido una excepción en el cliente que explique que se detenga el timer.

Answer (score 0):

Creo haber descubierto el origen del problema.

Resulta que tenía el siguiente fragmento `javascript` en mi fichero `.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function pageLoad() {
                var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
                prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
            }

            function EndRequest(){

            }

</script>
```

El problema de este código, si tienes un `timer` que se lanza cada pocos segundos, es que está añadiendo al `PageRequestManager` en el evento `end_request` la función `EndRequest` con cada ejecución del `timer`. Esto, al cabo del tiempo colapsa la memoria y la página detiene su ejecución, lógicamente.

Espero que a alguien le sirva esta experiencia si se ve en una situación similar.